# Android M Permissions Dialog - Choose Order Displayed to User

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

Is there a way to choose which order the user is prompted for permissions in Android Marshmellow's new permissions dialog?

When the user launches the camera in my app, I'm prompting for:

- Manifest.permission.CAMERA
- Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
- Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO

Because it makes the most sense (e.g. open camera, app requests camera permissions), I want the permissions to be requested in that order as well. But they aren't requested in that way - the Permissions dialog seems to just ignore the order I have in the String array.

Code below, using the [EasyPermissions library](https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions), but the same thing happens without the EasyPermissions library.

```
ArrayList<String> permissionsToRequest = new ArrayList<String>();
permissionsToRequest.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
permissionsToRequest.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
permissionsToRequest.add(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);

EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
            this,
            "To take pictures & record video, we need access to your device's camera & storage. Allow?",
            R.string.acceptPermission, R.string.declinePermission,
            RequestConstants.REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSIONS,
            permissionsToRequest.toArray(new String[0])
    );
```

Regardless of how I order the permissions in permissionsToRequest, the user is prompted in the same order (Audio, Storage, Camera), which in my opinion is the least intuitive order. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Well, everything about how the permissions are displayed to the user is undocumented and subject to change. Right now, it's a wizard-y thing. I can see it perhaps someday being different, particularly on tablets, where we have more screen space. I am not aware that there's a documented way to force the order, and even if there's some undocumented way, you can't really count on that long term.

Comment: So there is no way of ordering the permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Although there isn't a clear way to define the order of permission, I found that it is somehow related to the order defined in the AndroidManifest.xml and in the array passed in Activity.requestPermissions(String[] permissions, String requestCode)

In a device, the order of the permission array was the order it showed in the screen. In a different device, the order defined in the manifest prevailed.

Hope this helps.